# How to split a long GraphQL schema

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to create a Schema, however is going to get too long and confusing, what are the best practices to split the different queries, mutations and  inputs so I can just require them and organize them to make it easy to read.

I have tried to find information online but there is nothing clear at all and I am trying not to use Apollo.

```
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

module.exports = buildSchema(`
type Region {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  countries: [Country!]
}

type Country {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  region: [Region!]!
}

type City {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  country: [Country!]!
}

type Attraction {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  price: Float!
  description: String!
  city: [City!]!
}

type Eatery {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  cuisine: String!
  priceRange: String!
  location: [Location!]!
  typeOfEatery: String!
  city: [City!]!
}

type Location {
  _id: ID!
  latitude: String!
  longitude: String!
  address: Float
}

type User {
  _id: ID!
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

type AuthData {
  userId: ID!
  token: String!
  tokenExpiration: String!
}

type RegionInput {
  name: String!
}

type CountryInput {
  name: String!
}

type CityInput {
  name: String!
}

type RootQuery {
  regions: [Region!]!
  countries: [Country!]!
  login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthData!
}

type RootMutation {
  createRegion(regionInput: RegionInput): Region
  createCountry(countryInput: CountryInput): Country
  createCity(cityInput: CityInput): City
}

schema {
  query: RootQuery
  mutation: RootMutation
}
`);
```

I need something that is very organized and allows me to get everything in order and clear, merge all files in one index is the best solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are multiple options, here are three of them:

1. You can take a look at Apollo's blog - they show a way to modularize the schema: [Modularizing your GraphQL schema code](https://blog.apollographql.com/modularizing-your-graphql-schema-code-d7f71d5ed5f2)
   If you want an example, you can take a look at this [github repository](https://github.com/liron-navon/graphql-typescript-apollo-starter)
2. Of course you can always just use the template literals to embed parts of the schema as strings:

```
const countryType = `
type Country {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  region: [Region!]!
}
`

const regionType = `
type Region {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  countries: [Country!]
}
`

const schema = `
${countryType}
${regionType}

# ... more stuff ...
`

module.exports = buildSchema(schema);
```

3. Another way is to use the code first approach and write the schemas in javascript instead of graphql schema language.

Comment: So I can just create multiple files and them embed them into an index correct?

I'll look into Apollo in the future because I rather learn first to do it without using any other library. I need to understand the whole process first, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, but I love the Apollo approach though

Comment: Make sure you have at least one test where you call "buildSchema" since there can be duplicates, and "buildSchema" should throw an error at you if any duplicates exist.

Answer (score 3):

Make it separate folder and structure as well to make codes maintainable I do the following:

[GraphQL Example Repository](https://github.com/tunchamroeun/graphql-merge.git)

[File Structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBmb5.png)

```js
const express = require('express');
const glob = require("glob");
const {graphqlHTTP} = require('express-graphql');
const {makeExecutableSchema, mergeResolvers, mergeTypeDefs} = require('graphql-tools');
const app = express();
//iterate through resolvers file in the folder "graphql/folder/folder/whatever*-resolver.js"
let resolvers = glob.sync('graphql/*/*/*-resolver.js')
let registerResolvers = [];
for (const resolver of resolvers){
// add resolvers to array
    registerResolvers = [...registerResolvers, require('./'+resolver),]
}
//iterate through resolvers file in the folder "graphql/folder/folder/whatever*-type.js"
let types = glob.sync('graphql/*/*/*-type.js')
let registerTypes = [];
for (const type of types){
// add types to array
    registerTypes = [...registerTypes, require('./'+type),]
}
//make schema from typeDefs and Resolvers with "graphql-tool package (makeExecutableSchema)"
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: mergeTypeDefs(registerTypes),//merge array types
    resolvers: mergeResolvers(registerResolvers,)//merge resolver type
})
// mongodb connection if you prefer mongodb
require('./helpers/connection');
// end mongodb connection
//Make it work with express "express and express-graphql packages"
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,//test your query or mutation on browser (Development Only)
}));
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at http://localhost:4000/graphql');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Type definitions (SDL) merging](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/merge-typedefs) of `graphql-tools` as well.

> This tools merged GraphQL type definitions and schema. It aims to merge all possible types, interfaces, enums and unions, without conflicts.

The doc introduces multiple ways to merge SDL.

I made an example of [modularizing-the-schema](https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-server-express-starter/tree/master/src/modularizing-the-schema) using `apollo-server` tech stack.

Answer (score 1):

In typescript, you can put your graphQL schemas in file that you read from:

```js
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import path from "path";

function getTypeDefs(filename: string) {
    return gql(readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), 'resources', filename), 'utf8'));
}
```

Having a file structure looking like:

```
.
├── src
│   └── server.ts
└── resources
    ├── other.graphql
    └── schema.graphql
```

You can pass multiple gql in an array like:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-express";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: makeExecutableSchema({
        typeDefs: [getTypeDefs('schema.graphql'), getTypeDefs('other.graphql')],
        resolvers: YourResolvers
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a solution that doesn't involve apollo server this is something I've used in the past:

This script merges all `.graphql` files in a folder named `schema` into a single `schema.graphql` file

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "" >schema.graphql
find schema -name "*.graphql" -exec cat {} \; >>schema.graphql
```

Comment: So do we need to use this command line every time we make a change to an existing schema or adding a new schema?

Comment: Without a watcher of some sort, yes, @shortduck. 

You could add this as an `npm script` target: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts

Answer (score -2):

the best way follow my code s

i m use npm   typescripter express starter

```
export interface IGraphqlSchema {
  type?: string,
  query?: string,
  input?: string,
  mutation?: string,


}
```

```
export const sharedGraphqlSchema = {
  scalar: `
      scalar Void
      scalar Any
 `,

  rootSchema:
    `
schema {
query: RootQuery
mutation: RootMutation
}`
  ,
  rootQuery: "\ntype RootQuery {",

  rootMutation: "\ntype RootMutation {",


};
```

```
import { IGraphqlSchema } from "core/interfaces/graphql.schema";
import { sharedGraphqlSchema } from "./shared.graphql.schema";


export function combineSchemaGraphql(schemas: IGraphqlSchema[]): string {

  let combine: string = "";
  combine = combine.concat(sharedGraphqlSchema.scalar);
  let temp: string = "";


  for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < schemas.length; j++) {
      const item = schemas[j];
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          combine = combine.concat(item.type);
          break;
        case 1:
          combine = combine.concat(item.input);
          break;
        case 2:
          temp = temp.concat(item.query);

          break;

        default:
          temp = temp.concat(item.mutation);
          break;
      }

    }

    if (index == 2) {
      combine = combine.concat(sharedGraphqlSchema.rootQuery);
      combine = combine.concat(temp);
      combine = combine.concat("\n}");
      temp = "";
    }
    if (index == 3) {
      combine = combine.concat(sharedGraphqlSchema.rootMutation);
      combine = combine.concat(temp);
      combine = combine.concat("\n}");
    }

  }

  combine = combine.concat(sharedGraphqlSchema.rootSchema);

  return combine;
}
```

```
import { IGraphqlSchema } from "../../../core/interfaces/graphql.schema";

export const profileSchema: IGraphqlSchema = {

  type:
    `
  type Profile {
      _id: ID!
     firstName: String
     lastName: String
     userName: String
     password: String
     email: String
     phone: String
     image: String
     address: String
     gender: Boolean
     country: String
     city: String
     active: Boolean
     status: Boolean
     statusMessage: String
     createdAt: String
     updatedAt: String
     deletedAt: String
    }
   `,
  input:
    `
     input ProfileInputData {
         image: String
        firstName: String
        lastName: String
        country: String
        city: String
        password: String
        passConfirm: String
   }`,
  query:
    `
     profile: Profile!
`,
  mutation: `
 profileUpdate(inputs: ProfileInputData): Void
 `
};
```

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { StatusCodes } from "http-status-codes";
import { default as i18n } from "i18next";
import { RequestWithUser } from "../../auth/interfaces/reqeust.with.user.interface";
import ProfileService from "../services/profile.service";
import { UserEntity } from "../entities/user.entity";
import { IUser } from "../../auth/interfaces/user.interface";
import { isEmpty } from "./../../shared/utils/is.empty";
import { IMulterFile } from "./../../shared/interfaces/multer.file.interface";
import { optimizeImage } from "./../../shared/utils/optimize.image";
import { commonConfig } from "./../../common/configs/common.config";
import { IUserLogIn } from "@/modules/auth/interfaces/Log.in.interface";
import { ProfileValidation } from "@/modules/common/validations/profile.validation";
import { HttpException } from "@/core/exceptions/HttpException";
import { validateOrReject, Validator } from "class-validator";
import { warpValidationError } from "@/core/utils/validator.checker";
import { sharedConfig } from "@/modules/shared/configs/shared.config";

export const ProfileResolver = {

  profile: async function({ inputs }, req: RequestWithUser): Promise<void | any> {


    const user: IUserLogIn = req.user;

    const profileService = new ProfileService();
    const findOneData: IUser = await profileService.show(user._id);

    return {
      ...findOneData._doc
    };

  },


  profileUpdate: async function({ inputs }, req: RequestWithUser): Promise<void | Object> {

    const profileValidation = new ProfileValidation(inputs);

    try {
      await validateOrReject(profileValidation);

    } catch (e) {
      warpValidationError(e);
    }

    const user: IUserLogIn = req.user;
    const userEntity = new UserEntity(inputs);
    await userEntity.updateNow().generatePasswordHash();
    const profileService = new ProfileService();
    if (!isEmpty(req.file)) {

      const file: IMulterFile = req.file;
      // userEntity.image = commonConfig.profileDirectory + file.filename;
      userEntity.image = sharedConfig.publicRoot + file.filename;
      await optimizeImage(file.destination + file.filename, 200, 200, 60);
    }

    const updateData: IUser = await profileService.update(user._id, userEntity);



  }


};
```

```
import { settingSchema } from "@/modules/common/schemas/setting.schema";

process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = __dirname + "/core/configs";
import "dotenv/config";
import App from "./app";
import { merge } from "lodash";
import { combineSchemaGraphql } from "./core/utils/merge.graphql.type";
import { authSchema } from "@/modules/auth/schemas/auth.schema";
import { profileSchema } from "@/modules/common/schemas/profile.schema";
import { AuthResolver } from "@/modules/auth/resolvers/auth.resolver";
import { ProfileResolver } from "@/modules/common/resolvers/profile.resolver";
import { SettingResolver } from "@/modules/common/resolvers/setting.resolver";
import { sharedSchema } from "@/modules/shared/schemas/shared.schema";

const rootQuery = combineSchemaGraphql(
  [
    sharedSchema,
    authSchema,
    profileSchema,
    settingSchema]);

const mutation = merge(
  AuthResolver,
  ProfileResolver,
  SettingResolver);

const app = new App(rootQuery, mutation);
app.listen();
```

```
import { AppInterface } from "./core/interfaces/app.interface";

process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = __dirname + "/core/configs";

import compression from "compression";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import config from "config";
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import hpp from "hpp";
import morgan from "morgan";
import { connect, set } from "mongoose";
import swaggerJSDoc from "swagger-jsdoc";
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
import * as path from "path";
import * as fs from "fs";
import i18nMiddleware from "i18next-express-middleware";
import { default as i18n } from "i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-node-fs-backend";
import { LanguageDetector } from "i18next-express-middleware";
import { dbConnection } from "./core/databases/database.config";
import errorMiddleware from "./core/middlewares/error.middleware";
import { logger, stream } from "./core/utils/logger";
import contentNegotiationMiddleware from "./modules/common/middlewares/content.negotiation.middleware";
import corsMiddleware from "./modules/common/middlewares/cors.middleware";
import userAgent from "express-useragent";
import { graphqlHTTP } from "express-graphql";
import { buildSchema } from "graphql";
import authMiddleware from "@/modules/auth/middlewares/auth.middleware";
import multer from "multer";
import { multerFunctions, multerFileFilter } from "@/modules/shared/utils/multer.functions";
import { sharedConfig } from "@/modules/shared/configs/shared.config";

class App implements AppInterface {
  public app: express.Application;
  public port: string | number;
  public env: string;

  constructor(schema: string, resolver: object) {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
    this.env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
    this.initializeI18n();
    this.connectToDatabase();
    this.initializeMiddlewares();
    this.initializeSwagger();
    this.initializeErrorHandling();
    this.initGraphql(schema, resolver);

  }

  public listen(): void {
    this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
      logger.info(`====  typescript express.js modular graphql  kick starter ====`);
      logger.info(`===== by  ===== `);
      logger.info(`https://github.com/yasinpalizban`);
      logger.info(`======= ENV: ${this.env} =======`);
      logger.info(` App listening on the port ${this.port}`);

    });
  }

  public getServer(): express.Application {
    return this.app;
  }

  private connectToDatabase(): void {
    if (this.env !== "production") {
      set("debug", true);
    }

    connect(dbConnection.url, dbConnection.options);

  }

  private initializeMiddlewares(): void {
    this.app.use(morgan(config.get("log.format"), { stream }));
    this.app.use(corsMiddleware);
    this.app.use(hpp());
    this.app.use(helmet());
    this.app.use(compression());
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.app.use(cookieParser());
    this.app.use(userAgent.express());

    this.app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
    this.app.use(authMiddleware);

    this.app.use(contentNegotiationMiddleware);


    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: sharedConfig.publicRoot,
      filename: multerFunctions
    });
    const maxSize = 4 * 1000 * 1000;
    const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: multerFileFilter, limits: { fileSize: maxSize } });
    this.app.use(upload.array("image"));

  }


  private initializeSwagger(): void {
    const options = {
      swaggerDefinition: {
        info: {
          title: "REST API",
          version: "1.0.0",
          description: "Example docs"
        }
      },
      apis: ["swagger.yaml"]
    };

    const specs = swaggerJSDoc(options);
    this.app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(specs));
  }


  private initializeI18n(): void {

    i18n
      .use(Backend)
      .use(LanguageDetector)
      .init({
        lng: "en",
        whitelist: ["en", "fa"],
        fallbackLng: "en",
        // have a common namespace used around the full app
        ns: ["translation"],
        debug: false,
        backend: {
          loadPath: path.join(__dirname + "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json")
          // jsonIndent: 2
        },
        preload: ["en", "fa"]
      });
    this.app.use(i18nMiddleware.handle(i18n));

  }

  private initializeErrorHandling(): void {
    this.app.use(errorMiddleware);
  }

  private initGraphql(schema: string, resolver: object): void {

    this.app.use(
      "/graphql",
      graphqlHTTP({
        schema: buildSchema(schema),
        rootValue: resolver,
        graphiql: true,
        customFormatErrorFn: (error) => ({
          message: error.message,
          locations: error.locations,
          stack: error.stack ? error.stack.split('\n') : [],
          path: error.path,
        })
      //  customFormatErrorFn(err) {
          // if (!err.originalError) {
          //   return err;
          // }
          //
          // // @ts-ignore
          // const data = err.originalError.data;
          // const message = err.message || "An error occurred.";
          // // @ts-ignore
          // const code = err.originalError.status || 500;
          //
          // return { message: message, status: code, data: data };


      //  }
      })
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

your well come